Pandas Extract Sequence where prev value > current value
Need to extract sequence of negative values where earlier negative value is smaller than current value and next value is smaller than current value
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame with the given values
data = {
    'Value': [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4, -0.35, -0.25, 0.1, -0.15, -0.25, -0.13, -0.1, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)

My Code:
# Initialize a list to hold the sequences
sequences = []
current_sequence = []

# Iterate through the DataFrame to apply the condition
for i in range(1, len(df) - 1):
    prev_value = df.loc[i - 1, 'Value']
    curr_value = df.loc[i, 'Value']
    next_value = df.loc[i + 1, 'Value']
    
    # Check the condition
    if curr_value < prev_value and curr_value < next_value:
        current_sequence.append(curr_value)
    else:
        # If the current sequence is not empty and it's a valid sequence, add it to sequences list and reset
        if current_sequence:
            sequences.append(current_sequence)
            current_sequence = []

# Add the last sequence if it's not empty
if current_sequence:
    sequences.append(current_sequence)

My Output:
Extracted Sequences:
[-0.4]
[-0.25]

Expected Output:
[-0.1,-0.2,-0.3,-0.4]
[-0.15,-0.25]


Are you sure of desired output ? because if both earlier and next values need to be smaller than current value, i don't see how you would extract any of the values in desired output. Like current value -0.4 : -0.4 < -0.3 and -0.4<-0.35

Could you give the expected output if you replace -0.25 by -0.45?

how come earlier -0.1 is smaller than -0.2 in your expected output? do you mean absolute value?

You can build masks to identify the negative values and consecutive decreasing values and use groupby to split:
# is the value negative?
m1 = df['Value'].lt(0)

# is the value decreasing?
m2 = df['Value'].diff().le(0)

m = m1&m2

# aggregate
out = df[m].groupby((~m).cumsum())['Value'].agg(list).tolist()

Output:
[[-0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4], [-0.15, -0.25]]

If you just want to filter:
out = df[m]

Output:
    Value
3   -0.10
4   -0.20
5   -0.30
6   -0.40
10  -0.15
11  -0.25

Intermediates:
    Value     m1  df['Value'].diff()     m2  m1&m2
0    0.30  False                 NaN  False  False
1    0.20  False               -0.10   True  False
2    0.10  False               -0.10   True  False
3   -0.10   True               -0.20   True   True
4   -0.20   True               -0.10   True   True
5   -0.30   True               -0.10   True   True
6   -0.40   True               -0.10   True   True
7   -0.35   True                0.05  False  False
8   -0.25   True                0.10  False  False
9    0.10  False                0.35  False  False
10  -0.15   True               -0.25   True   True
11  -0.25   True               -0.10   True   True
12  -0.13   True                0.12  False  False
13  -0.10   True                0.03  False  False
14   1.00  False                1.10  False  False


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {'Value': [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4, -0.35, -0.25, 0.1, -0.15, -0.25, -0.13, -0.1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

values = df['Value'].values

negative = values < 0
df['negative'] = negative

decreasing = np.concatenate(([False], np.diff(values) <= 0))
df['decreasing'] =decreasing

mask = negative & decreasing
df['mask'] =mask
print(df)
'''
    Value  negative  decreasing   mask
0    0.30     False       False  False
1    0.20     False        True  False
2    0.10     False        True  False
3   -0.10      True        True   True
4   -0.20      True        True   True
5   -0.30      True        True   True
6   -0.40      True        True   True
7   -0.35      True       False  False
8   -0.25      True       False  False
9    0.10     False       False  False
10  -0.15      True        True   True
11  -0.25      True        True   True
12  -0.13      True       False  False
13  -0.10      True       False  False
14   1.00     False       False  False
'''
start_sequence = np.where(mask[1:] & ~mask[:-1])[0] +1 
print(start_sequence)#[ 3 10]

end_sequence =  np.where(~mask[1:] & mask[:-1])[0] +1 
print(end_sequence)#[ 7 12]

desired_sequence = [values[start:end].tolist() for start,end in zip(start_sequence,end_sequence)]
print(desired_sequence )

'''
[[-0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4], [-0.15, -0.25]]
'''


My Solution:
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame with the given values
data = {
    'Value': [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4, -0.35, -0.25, 0.1, -0.15, -0.25, -0.13, -0.1, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def select_rows_based_on_criteria2(df, column_name):
    selected_indices = []

    for i in range(1, len(df) - 1):  # Skip the first and last rows for comparison
        prev_value = df[column_name].iloc[i - 1]
        curr_value = df[column_name].iloc[i]
        next_value = df[column_name].iloc[i + 1]

        if curr_value < 0 and next_value < curr_value: #prev_value < 0 and
            # selected_indices.append(df.index[i - 1])
            selected_indices.append(df.index[i])
            selected_indices.append(df.index[i + 1])
            # selected_indices.append(df.index[i + 2])
            # selected_indices.append(df.index[i + 3])
            # selected_indices.append(df.index[i + 4])
    # Use a set to avoid duplicate indices and then sort them
    selected_indices = sorted(set(selected_indices))
    selected_rows = df.loc[selected_indices]

    return selected_rows
selected_rows41 = select_rows_based_on_criteria2(df, 'Value')
selected_rows41

Output:
Value
3   -0.10
4   -0.20
5   -0.30
6   -0.40
10  -0.15
11  -0.25


Please don't use the above solution. Go through the codes provided by me and my friend mozway.@Divyank
